# Can an intelligent item use another item?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

The intelligent item class description from The Complete Book of Eldritch Might indicates that magic items can speak, and that with the feat Animate self they can "manipulate objects in a crude way".

Would an intelligent item be able to use other magic items? Ie. a sword activating a crystal or an intelligent spider shaped medallion activating a wand?

Comment: Does the source mention whether members of the intelligent item class are creatures?  I know core intelligent items are explicitly constructs, but I'm not familiar with the third-party version beyond what's in post and [the answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/110564/30299) to your other question.

Comment: @A_S00  It describes them as being of the "construct creature type"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes - as long as they meet the other requirements for doing so.

The [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemBasics.htm) and the Magic Item Compendium (pp. 219-220) summarize the rules for using magic items, and don't include any restrictions that would prevent a character who was an intelligent item from doing so.  The only restrictions listed are those based on specific capabilities - for instance, in order to use an item whose activation item is Command Word, you have to be able to speak.

Since the intelligent item class you're using is explicitly able to speak and manipulate objects, most forms of activation are going to be possible.  The major exception to watch out for is missing body slots.  The Magic Item Compendium (p. 219) has rules for body slots on creatures with non-standard body shapes (e.g., creatures without legs don't get a feet slot, etc.).  Depending on what kind of item the character is, several of these are likely to apply.

This character would also be unable to use [potions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/potionsAndOils.htm), since...

> A creature must be able to swallow a potion or smear on an oil.

Comment: The oil might work, but they'd still have to be able to smear, or have someone do it for them... plus it might have to work on objects, depending on the DM in question. Good catch on the missing body slots issue!